# IntegrityError at /api/img/ null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-serializer

django rest framework post request error 
Here is the image model

```
class Img(models.Model):
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="img")
    picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='fake_picture',null=True,blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

Here is the image serializer for model Img

```
class ImgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField(required=False)
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    # post   = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Img
        fields='__all__'
```

views.py

```
class ImgViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    permission_classes =[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]
    authentication_classes =(TokenAuthentication,JSONWebTokenAuthentication)
    queryset = Img.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ImgSerializer
```

but when ever a post request to that particular api endpoint is triggered from the post man with key value pair as

```
picture:image.jpg
```

this is what the response is

```
IntegrityError at /api/img/
null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, fake_picture/2019-06-27_at_10-04-59.png, 2020-05-05 23:06:00.16071+00, null).


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/img/
```

[image: post request to that endpoint]

[image: with headers]

Comment: You’ve set read_only on the author field on your serializer but the field is required on your model. You need to set the field before you save the model

Comment: considering your point 
i have removed read_only=True 
still there is error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
class ImgViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ..........
    serializer_class=ImgSerializer
    .......
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.save(author=serializer.context['request'].user)
```